# Short URL of a comment is not picked up in the "Linked" questions list

Tags: bug, comments, linked-questions

Here is a short URL of a comment on a different Meta SE post:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/594902

However, the question under which this comment appears is not added to the "Linked" questions list for this post, and neither does this post appear under the "Linked" questions list of the other one.

There is no issue if the short URL format is used for questions or answers, such as `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/*` or `https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/*`. Such links are picked up appropriately to appear in the "Linked" questions list. Only the short URLs of comments are not picked up. Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Here is a short URL of a comment on yet another Meta SE post, to show that the problem also occurs if such a short link is posted in the comments: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1061920. The link in the post goes to a comment under a question, and the link in this comment goes to a comment under an answer.